# pointer of a pointer and memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

If I have `int **array` and want to place a series of numbers in it (I don't know its size), `5 3 4 0` or `9 1 5 8 3 0` as an example. As far as I know I should be using `malloc`

So I did something like this

```
int **array;
int n = 1, inp = 0;
while(n){ // scan till the input is 0
    scanf("%d", &n);
    array = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*(inp+1)); //since inp start at 0
    array[inp] = &n; //is this even correct?
    inp++;
}
```

My first question is: Will this method (the loop) upgrade/expand the size of the `array` or is what I am doing a waste of memory?

The second question is how can I print/edit the values of this `array`?

**EDIT:**

From your answers I have came up with the following.

```
int **array;
int n = 1, inp = 0;
array = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*));
while(n){
    scanf("%d", &n);
    realloc( array, sizeof((int*)(inp+1)));
    array[inp] = n;
    inp++;
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Note* I am aware that it does not have to be a pointer of a pointer, but I need it to be for something else later on.

Comment: This array[inp] = &n; does not make sense because all elements of the array will have the same value: address of the variable n.

Comment: Why the double pointer? Don't you just want a 1D array of ints? And no, malloc inside a loop is a bad idea. realloc is better.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` for this - it's all wrong. Use `realloc`

Comment: ... and a pointer with an initial NULL value.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I am going to be adding more 1D arrays into it later on.

Comment: @user9138715 - No, your update is not correct! BTW: Why do you want a double pointer?

Comment: @4386427 can you please explain what I did wrong? I need a double pointer to add more arrays to it later on, so a 2D array.

Comment: @user9138715 - you can't store `int` values in a pointer-to-pointer-to-int.

Comment: @user9138715 An `int*` can point to an array of `int`. But a `int**` can only point to an array of `int*`. Therefor you can't save `int` into that memory.

Comment: Well, you can, but you must allocate memory for each of the pointers you allocate. E.g. `int **foo`. Then `foo = malloc (10 * sizeof *foo)` to allocate 10 pointers to `int`. Then to allocate the first array `foo[0] = malloc (20 * sizeof *foo[0]);` to allocate storage for `20` `int` in array `foo[0]` and so on.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - true, true... but that's not what OP is doing. The example after the edit stores integer values directly into integer pointers. That's bad

Comment: Yes, but that is what he is describing attempting to do, even though if there is just 1 array of `int`, then there is no need for the pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: @user9138715 Compare your second example with the second example in my answer. You'll notice a few but important differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is wrong for at least these reasons.

1) You keep doing `malloc` to `array` and thereby loose previously `malloced` blocks. The function to use is `realloc` when extending the size of dynamic memory.

2) You store the address of `n` instead of the value of `n`

Besides that it seems strange to use a double pointer. Why not do like:

```
int *array = NULL;
int n = 1, inp = 0;
while(n){ // scan till the input is 0
    scanf("%d", &n);
    array = realloc(array, sizeof(int)*(inp+1));
    array[inp] = n;
    inp++;
}
```

**EDIT after OPs update**

If you really want to use a double pointer (i.e. `int **array;`), you need to allocate memory in two levels.

That could look like:

```
int **array = malloc(sizeof *array);
*array = NULL;
int n = 1, inp = 0;
while(n){ // scan till the input is 0
    scanf("%d", &n);
    *array = realloc(*array, sizeof(int)*(inp+1));
    (*array)[inp] = n;
    inp++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing in your code is allocating progressively larger areas of memory and saving the input value in the last position of each new area, while losing the pointers to the previously allocated areas. A commom and efficient solution for what you want (which is used in C++'s vectors, I believe) is to allocate some minimum amount of space, then check at each iteration if you are on the verge of exceeding it. In case you are, reallocate the area doubling the space. Something like this:

```
int i = 0; //iterator
int s = 1; //array size
int n;     //input (use do-while so you don't have to worry about initial value)

//it doesn't have to be bidimensional for a single series
int * array = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * s);

do
{
    if(i == s)
    {
        s *= 2;
        array = (int *) realloc(array, sizeof(int) * s);
    }
    scanf("%d", &n);
    array[i++] = n; //assign with the value, not with the address
}
while(n)
```

**UPDATE:** if you really need to use **int, do it like this:

```
int n, i = 0, s = 1;

int ** array = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int*) * s);

do
{
    if(i == s)
    {
        s *= 2;
        array = (int **) realloc(array, sizeof(int *) * s);
    }
    scanf("%d", &n);
    array[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    array[i][0] = n;
    ++i;
}
while(n)
```